# Windows web browser or extension/plugin with multiline address bar

Tags: windows, web-browser, url

I need to reverse engineer a website where the URL changes depending on where I click on the page.

It will be much easier if I can see all of the URL at the same time.

Is there a windows browser or extension/plugin which will show a multi line address bar? I don't mind if I need to set the number of lines myself or if it adjusts it automatically.

I only have one screen and cannot stretch the window beyond one screen.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers today have developer tools build into them. Usually available by pressing F12.

The Network pane in those tools should provide you the list you need.

Unless I'm missing the point completely.

Comment: Mixed feelings: The idea sounds promising but it seems the only way to see all of the link in one go is by hovering over bits of the dev tab. Unless there is something else I need to click - if thats's the case, please feel free to highlight on [my screenshot](https://imgur.com/UGJLlR7.jpg) - I'm afraid it seems to open in the current tab by default.

Comment: Seeing the screenshot, what are you wishing to extract.
One place I would start with is the filters, on that line you can filter the collected content based on a regex or predefined categories.

Answer (score 1):

Using a clipboard manager (CopyQ), I can view the entire URL by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (focus address bar and select URL) followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (invoke CopyQ window). You might be able to use AutoKey or AutoHotKey to get that down to one keyboard shortcut.